# Iterator always poiting the last element

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I'm doing a program with C++, and when I try to list my vector elements it always shows the last element.

Here is my code:

```
typedef string Tab[1][1]; 
struct Node
{
  Tab t1;
};
```

and here is how I list my elements:

```
std::vector<Node*>::iterator itr;

for(itr = Tab_dynamique.begin(); itr != Tab_dynamique.end(); *itr++)
{
  cout << (*itr)->t1[0][0] << " | " << (*itr)->t1[0][1]<< endl;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's always showing the last element of the vector?

Comment: try `itr++` (without dereferencing)

Comment: Can you give a [minimal sample the reproduces this behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: As far as I see this should always show the first element. And always means you result in an infinite loop by doing *itr++.

Comment: Although unnecessary, why does the `*` in `*itr++` prevent it from working? https://ideone.com/9IZCoQ

Comment: Why my question is rated -2 ??? O.o

Comment: Anyway i found the solution to this problem, without Stack.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, at least according to what you showed us, but:

1. Your array `typedef string Tab[1][1]` has only one element: `Tab[0][0]`, `Tab[0][1]` is out of range. For example `int tab[3]` has the following 3 elements: `tab[0], tab[1], tab[2]`.
2. You should not increment your iterator as you did (`*itr++`). First your dereferencing is unnecessary and not really has any impact on your incrementation of iterator. Second you should increment your iterator that way: `++itr`, because `itr++` creates redundant copy of `itr` for returning, and then only increment iterator.

Comment: Hi, i did what you said and it's always showing the same result, the last element of the list.

Comment: Maybe at first you put in Tab_dynamique some NULL element? Add to your post how you declare Tab_dynamique and how you fill your elements in your vector. We will continue looking for solution then.

Comment: i found the problem, it's that the Tab t1 takes every time the last value, and never changes it.
but i can't find the solution of that :/

Comment: What is the size of Tab_dynamique before for loop? Code: `vector<Node*>::sizeof()`?

Comment: it gives the same size of the vector, but when i try to get the value it always gives the value of the last assigned node,